# IOS app that displays a Facebook group

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, uiwebview

I would like to know what is the best way to show a Facebook group in an iOS app.

I have a iOS app that uses Facebook logins for the users to access content. I thought I might be able to display the a Facebook group using a UIWebView. The problem is when the Facebook group webpage the opened, the user is presented with a login. As the user has already logged into my app using Facebook, I am wondering if its possible to use the current access token to inform Facebook that the user is already logged in.

If that doesn't work, how else could I add a Facebook Group to a iOS app? Is there a sample app somewhere that displays Facebook page is a UIViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, if you want to show FB content in a `UIWebView`, the user must perform the login inside the `UIWebView`. You cannot share your access token with the web-view.

A possible solution would be to use the graph API (you're already using the FB iOS SDK, right?) to retrieve the group info, feed etc. and show it to your users. The downside is that you'll have to create and display the group info yourself with your own design.

You can take a look at the FB graph API for groups [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group).